# What is the extreme value distribution for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov D statistic?

Tags: statistics, extreme-value-analysis

I occasionally find that I want to apply a K-S test in the context of unit-testing software that involves random behaviors. Unit testing with sampling statistics is a bit tricky because you want to minimize false-failures.

Extreme value distributions are one likely approach to minimizing false positives, since they make it possible to run a series of experiments, find a maximum D statisic between experimental results and an expected distribution, and measure the probability that D is an outlier using Extreme Value theory.

The idea is that I might run (n) K-S tests, comparing n pairs of samples. This will result in n D-statistic values; the maximum of these values will adhere to some variation of extreme value distribution.

I am looking for some closed-form expression for the extreme value distribution for the K-S D statistic. I suspect it at least adheres to the Weibull form of the EV distribution since its value has a finite maximum, but not even sure of that. I might do some empirical fitting but a more general formula would be even nicer.

UPDATE:
Although I have posted an answer that works for a given sample size, it would also be interesting to derive a limiting cdf, that is identify $\alpha$ for the Weibull family of EVD:
$$
F(x) = e^{-(-(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}))^\alpha}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe I see the solution. Provided you know the cdf of your iid random variables F(x), the cdf for the maximum value over n iid samples is just (F(x))^n, for example [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory#Univariate_theory).

And I *can* compute the cdf I need. For a Kolmogorov-Smirnov D statistic over a sample size n (Dn), the quantity sqrt(n)*Dn converges to the Kolmogorov distribution, and its cdf is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution); there are also numeric [algorithms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5142829_Evaluating_Kolmogorov%27s_Distribution) for computing it, including [implementations](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/KolmogorovSmirnovDistribution.html).